# define a function from a list

Tags: function-construction

I would like to create a mapping from a list and I am wondering if there is a slick way of doing it.

For example, consider the list

```
ls = WaveletFilterCoefficients[DaubechiesWavelet[2], "PrimalHighpass"]

{{-2, -0.0915064},{-1, -0.158494},{0, 0.591506},{1, -0.341506}}
```

I would like to define a function that maps

```
 -2 -> -0.0915064
 -1 -> -0.158494
  0 ->  0.591506
  1 -> -0.341506
```

and all other integers to zero.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Scan[]` is your friend:

```
Scan[(f[First[#]] = Last[#]) &, 
  WaveletFilterCoefficients[DaubechiesWavelet[2], "PrimalHighpass"]];
f[_] = 0;

??f
  Global`f
f[-2]=-0.0915064

f[-1]=-0.158494

f[0]=0.591506

f[1]=-0.341506

f[_]=0
```

Answer (score 9):

You could easily create a pattern doing the replacement for you:

```
ls = WaveletFilterCoefficients[DaubechiesWavelet[2], "PrimalHighpass"];
rule = Rule @@@ ls
```

> ```
> {-2 -> -0.0915064,
>  -1 -> -0.158494,
>   0 ->  0.591506,
>   1 -> -0.341506}
> ```

This can now be used as usual, for example

```
{-1, 1} /. rule
```

> ```
> {-0.158494, -0.341506}
> ```

If you want to map all integers to 0, append (!) this to your rule list:

```
AppendTo[rule, _ -> 0];
```

> ```
> {-2 -> -0.0915064,
>  -1 -> -0.158494,
>   0 ->  0.591506,
>   1 -> -0.341506,
>   _ -> 0}
> ```

Be careful though, because when you apply this to a list as before it'll match the whole list as `_`, replacing it with 0:

```
1 /. rule
```

> ```
> -0.341506
> ```

```
{0, 1} /. rule
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

To properly do the list replacement in this case, use something like

```
myReplace = # /. rule &;
myReplace /@ {0, 1}
```

> ```
> {0.591506, -0.341506}
> ```

Comment: If your list is long you will want `rule = Dispatch[ Rule @@@ ls ]` for performance.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your application this may be most efficient:

```
pts =
  {{-2, -0.0915064},
   {-1, -0.158494},
   { 0,  0.591506},
   { 1, -0.341506}};

f = Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 0];

f /@ {1, -1, -2, 0}
```

> ```
> {-0.341506, -0.158494, -0.158494, 0.591506}
> ```

This assumes that your function will only be given arguments that are in your list rather that points between them, which will otherwise effectively give `f[Floor[#]] &`.

---

Also, I recognize the advantage of `Scan` but I cannot pass the syntactical elegance of:

```
(f[#] = #2) & @@@ pts;
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not use `Replace`?

```
ls = WaveletFilterCoefficients[DaubechiesWavelet[2], "PrimalHighpass"];    

Attributes[func] = {Listable};
func[x_] := Replace[x, Apply[Rule, ls, {1}]];

func[{1, 0, -1, -2}]

(*
   ==> {-0.341506, 0.591506, -0.158494, -0.0915064}
*)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use `Map` i.e. `/@` :

```
 l= WaveletFilterCoefficients[DaubechiesWavelet[2], "PrimalHighpass"];    
 Set[f[#[[1]]], #[[2]]] & /@ l;  
 f[_] = 0;
 f /@ Range[-3, 3]
 (*
 ==>  {0, -0.0915064, -0.158494, 0.591506, -0.341506, 0, 0}
 *)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that `Map[]` can have the side-effect of *producing output*, which might be problematic if the list is long, and you've forgotten the semicolon. `Scan[]` is guaranteed not to produce output.

Comment: @J.M. Sorry, where have I missed the semicolon ?

Comment: You didn't, but it's a common mistake to forget semicolons for delineating different expressions.

Comment: @J.M. I'd add that even if you don't miss a semicolon, memory is allocated and list is internally created when `Map` is used. So, `Map` and `Scan` have very different memory use characteristics. If `Scan` can be used (meaning no output is needed), it is IMO better to use it than `Map`. Also, conceptually, this makes an intent of producing side-effects more clear / transparent.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks for filling in, @Leonid!

Comment: @J.M. But I must admit that I also sometimes use `Map` in such situations (just  because its syntax is more concise :))