# Defining an integer-valued function on an integer domain

Tags: function-construction

This should be an easy question! I want to define a function with domain = the 12 integers `{1,12}`, with the values `f[1]=31`, `f[2]=28`, `f[3]=31`, etc. (number of days in the month).  This will be a part of nested `Do[]` loops running through the days of a non-leap year for a particular data set I am working with.

Comment: It seems that within the statement of the question you have already gone one-quarter of the way to defining your entire function.  Why not just complete the process?

Comment: @whuber Because it doesn't scale if he later wants to have `f[m,d] = <hours per day>`.  Who'd want to type all 365(6) entries in by hand?

Comment: I didn't see any scaling requirement in the question, Brett.  Sometimes the obvious method can be the best solution.

Comment: @whuber Well, there goes my attempt at humor for the day...

Comment: Too subtle for me, I guess.  How can it be humor without a smiley?  :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
f[x_ /; MemberQ[Range@12, x]] := Switch[x, 2, 28, 4 | 6 | 9 | 11, 30, _, 31]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Nice generalizable solution with tight control of both the domain and range.

Answer (score 13):

I advise against using `Switch` to implement this function because it is considerably slower than other pattern matching.

Here is the `AbsoluteTiming` for the `Switch` method on my machine:

```
f[x_ /; MemberQ[Range@12, x]] := Switch[x, 2, 28, 4 | 6 | 9 | 11, 30, _, 31]

f /@ RandomInteger[20, 500000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.3250758, Null}
> ```

Here is the same thing avoiding `Switch` and `Condition`:

```
g[2] = 28;
g[4 | 6 | 9 | 11] = 30;
g[1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 8 | 10 | 12] = 31;

g /@ RandomInteger[20, 500000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.2070119, Null}
> ```

Here is direct definition for each value (`h[1] = 31; h[2] = 28; . . .`):

```
months = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

Inner[(h[#] = #2) &, Range@12, months, List];

h /@ RandomInteger[20, 500000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.1950112, Null}
> ```

Here is a related operation using a `Dispatch` table and `Replace`.  All values other than (1 .. 12) are replaced with zero:

```
rls = Dispatch @ Append[Thread[Range[12] -> months], _ -> 0];

Replace[RandomInteger[20, 500000], rls, {1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0670038, Null}
> ```

Comment: Wow.  This is very interesting.  In my application it doesn't matter because the function only gets called 12 times in a Do[ ] loop, but this would be very important in an iterated application.

Answer (score 6):

How about this, which takes the name of the variable (eg `f`) as an argument, uses Mathematicas' date functionality to obtain the last day of each month in a given year and defines `f[n]` as the number of days in month `n`:

```
def[year_, var_] := MapThread[
  (var[#1] = #2) &,
  {
   Range[12],
   Part[
    DatePlus[{year - 1, 12, 31}, {#, "Month"}] & /@ Range[12],
    All, 3
    ]
   }
  ]
```

eg, for 2011 (which was not leap)

```
def[2011, f]
(*{31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}*)
```

and then eg

```
f[2]
```

gives `28`. On the other hand,

```
def[2008, f]
(*{31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}*)
```

takes into account the fact that 2008 was leap.

EDIT: Note that this defines [`DownValues`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-is-the-distinction-between-downvalues-upvalues-subvalues-and-ownvalues) for `var`, or `f` in the example above, as may be seen from either `?f` or `DownValues[f]`.

Comment: Another great solution, but more than I need at this moment, since I am combining data from several years at once (and I ignore 29 Feb).  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution making use of the fact that you can assign to a list of variables:

```
Set[Evaluate[f /@ Range[12]], {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}]
```

although with this approach you can only do it once.  (Otherwise the `Evaluate` will turn `f[1]` into `31` before assignment occurs, and you'll get an error.)

Comment: Thanks.  I have found the Evaluate[ ] function confusing…  This helps.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably the simplest way to define it:

```
(f[#]=31)&/@Range[12]
(f[#]=30)&/@{4,6,9,11} 
f[2]=28
```

Comment: Another great approach.  I love learning these tricks.  Thanks!

Comment: `Scan[]` would be a better thing to use here than `Map[]`.

Comment: @J.M.: Better in what way?

Comment: See the discussion under the comments [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1828).

Comment: @J.M.: I see, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
Do[f[n] = 30 + Boole[Xor[OddQ[n], n>7]] - 2 Boole[n == 2], {n,12}]
```

One could also do the calculation at run time:

```
f[n_Integer /; 1 <= n <= 12] :=
  30 + Boole[Xor[OddQ[n], n>7]] - 2 Boole[n == 2]
```

Or with memoization:

```
f[n_Integer /; 1 <= n <= 12] :=
  f[n] = 30 + Boole[Xor[OddQ[n], n>7]] - 2 Boole[n == 2]
```

Comment: Where did you learn this?