# Indexed variable with alternatives

Tags: variable-definitions

I have

```
a["tree"] := "oak"
a["flower"] := "rose"
a["dog" | "cat"] := "animals"
```

I want that the last definition of `a` behaves differently like in

```
b[x_ /; x == "dog" || x == "cat"] := If[x == "dog", "wow", "miau"]
```

but  want to  do this with `a`

Is there a way to write something like

```
a["dog" | "cat"] := If[ (* passed parameter *) == "dog", "wow", "miau"]
```

Comment: Like `a[x : "dog" | "cat"] := Switch[x, "dog", 1, "cat", 2]`? P.s. there is not need for `:=` in first two cases.

Comment: @Kuba - That's exactly what I was looking for and couldn't find. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should avoid `Switch` if possible; please read this: [(2618)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2618)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest and fastest (execution time) method is to simply use two definitions:

```
a["dog"] = "wow";
a["cat"] = "miau";
```

On reflection this is so straightforward that I doubt I understand your question or the reason behind it.  Could you give another example, please?

A related question:

- [Defining an integer-valued function on an integer domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/defining-an-integer-valued-function-on-an-integer-domain/2618#2618)

Comment: The reason behind my question was that I thought I could keep a long story short by using `Alternatives`. I agree that a `Swift` makes it long again, but would not say at this point that Kuba's comment is without advantages in some cases.

Comment: @eldo Could you give an example where you feel that multiple definitions is clumsy?  Perhaps I can recommend a way to improve it.  For the existing example I strongly recommend this method over `Switch` for both performance and clarity.

Comment: @eldo you can make it more compact if you need: `alt = {"dog", "cat"};
val = {1, 2};
ClearAll[a];
MapThread[Set, {a /@ alt, val}];`

Comment: @Kuba You can even enter values as a 2D table a la `Piecewise`, if this is a matter of visual formatting.  (Assuming use of the Notebook interface.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Reading "2618", I would recommend to myself your second ansatz ( `g[2] = 28` ... ) because of its clarity. In a certain sense my question was a duplicate. You should add that link to your answer.

Comment: @eldo Link added as requested.