# Converting format of list

Tags: formatting, list-manipulation

I have a 2D array,

```
data = {{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}};
```

I would like to convert it such that I get the x- and y-values separately, specifically

```
x[0]=0; x[1]=1; x[2]=2;
y[0]=1; y[1]=2; y[2]=3;
```

Is there a way to obtain this?

Comment: You could do it in many differernt ways however the most appropriate tool for this task is `Scan`, this is a duplicate of [define a function from a list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/define-a-function-from-a-list)

Comment: @Artes This question is a little bit different than the linked question because here we have to iterate the `x[i]` (i.e. we have to know where we are in the list during scanning). Anyway here's my first attempt at using `Scan`: `Scan[{x[#[[3]]]=#[[1]],y[#[[3]]]=#[[2]]}&,MapIndexed[Join,data]]`. If anyone has a better implementation I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**  Öskå informs me that what you wanted is not in fact what you asked for.  Next time ask the right question to get the right answer.  Output formatting is often completely different and if that is your goal you need to clearly state it.

```
f[v_, {r_, c_}] := HoldForm[#[#2] = v;] &[{"x", "y"}[[c]], r - 1]

out = MapIndexed[f, data, {2}]\[Transpose] // Grid
```

> ```
> x[0]=0; x[1]=1; x[2]=2;
> y[0]=1; y[1]=2; y[2]=3;
> ```

You can use **Copy As** > **Plain Text** to copy that output, or you can export it like this:

```
Export["file.txt", ToString[out, StandardForm]]
```

---

I don't see the point of making the assignments that you describe.
[`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) is a fast operation so you might simply use that:

```
x[n_] := data[[n + 1, 1]]
y[n_] := data[[n + 1, 2]]
```

With different data to make the example more clear:

```
data = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};

Array[x, 3, 0]
Array[y, 3, 0]
```

> ```
> {a, c, e}
>
> {b, d, f}
> ```

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56634/converting-format-of-list#comment162436_56636

Comment: @Öskå Noted.  A very poorly written question in that case. :-/

Comment: Indeed, but I personally didn't bother trying to understand it. I assumed that the OP knew about `Part` and that there was something behind (his profile talks about C/C++).

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the prettiest but here you go:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}};
(x[#] = (First /@ data)[[#2]]) & @@@ 
  Thread@{Range[0, Length[First /@ data] - 1], Range[Length[First /@ data]]};
(y[#] = (Last /@ data)[[#2]]) & @@@ 
  Thread@{Range[0, Length[Last /@ data] - 1], Range[Length[Last /@ data]]};

?x
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The semicolon is missing, can that be added?

Comment: I don't see how. What's the purpose of this? You could just treat it as a string if you _need_ it.

Comment: I need the data for C, so there has a be a semicolon. Otherwise I have to add it manually, but its a large data set.

Comment: Added the semicolon myself by stringjoin

Comment: @BillyJean Great, like I said, it all depends on what you wanted to do with it :)

Answer (score 2):

One-liner:

```
MapThread[Set, {{x[#], y[#]} & /@ Range[0, Length@data - 1], data}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 however this will fail to reassign values.  Also, the OP wanted to index from zero.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard could you help me understand how my method fails to reassign value? Thanks for the upvote! BTW I need help with belisarius' answer on another Q&A that came from one of your answers ([ref](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56638/merging-lists-and-adding-common-elements/56644?noredirect=1#comment162513_56644)]). Could you point me to the right Q&A or help me understand what's going on in that piece of code?

Comment: I mean that if e.g. `x[1]` already has a value it will evaluate before `Set` sees it, so you'll be doing effectively `1 = 2` or whatever.  You would need to hold that expression somehow.  If you cannot see a solution for that, and you are interested, post this code in a Question asking how it may be modified to allow reassignment for existing definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data[[All,1]]` for all `x` coordinates and  `data[[All,2]]` for all `y` coordinates